# .mp4 videos not playing on mobile

Tags: html5-video, mp4

I'm having issues with my .mp4 vidoes not playing on mobile on either Chrome or Safari (haven't tried Explorer or Mozilla). This is the code that I am using for the videos:

```
<video autoplay loop autobuffer muted playsinline style="width:100%; height:auto;">
<source src="/static_imgs/lo_macbook_mockup.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<img src="/static_imgs/lo_site_reskin_img.jpg" title="Legal Outreach site reskin." />
</video>
```

I've tried with and without playsinline and muted but still nothing. Works fine on desktop. The site with the videos listed is https://bigsheep.design/projects/legal-outreach-4

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the H264 profile of **High @ Level 5** is not supported on your test mobile device.

Try to export (or re-encode) the video with a `Profile` settings of **Baseline @ Level 3**.
 This basic profile can decoded by the video chips in most devices, after that you can try increasing up to **Main** and try different **Levels** for it.

In your video encoding tool, you want to find similar option to this (*image from Handbrake tool*):

[image]

Comment: This might work! I actually just gave up and resorted a .gif for one video and a still image for the other. I appreciate the advice! If I do this in the future I'll try your suggestion. Also, my test mobile device was my iPhone 8, which I imagine this would work on, but who knows. Thanks for the suggestion!!!